# How to publish/subscribe SNS notification in Web App from AWS SNS. And we are using angular as front end technology

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-sns

We have requirement to publish/subscribe SNS notification in Web App from AWS SNS. And we are using angular as front end technology.

So, need guidance as SNS support Http/Https protocol so in such case do we need to configure our webapp URL instead of REST API in SNS topic/subscription to receive notification? Unable to understand how web app will listen event from SNS.

Or, do we need to expose REST API in our backend code for SNS subscription confirmation and to receive notification from AWS SNS. It will work as webhook.

But, if we opt 2nd approach (REST API) then how will backend will notify to frontend (angular code) without sync call. I mean in that case frontend would have to do polling through api call to get update from server for SNS notification.

Or, we should use signalR to notify the frontend once we received SNS notification at server side.

Comment: Did you know how to do it?

Comment: @DAMAR225 - We have configured the Webhook in server side and the configured Webhook API in SNS Topic with Https protocol. And now we are able to receive notification via webhook.